# trouble with aura:iteration and JSON object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, lightning-design-system, aura, aura-iteration

I have a Helper function with the following JSON:

```
getUsersVacationItemsList : function (component, event) {                 
var tableRow =[
   {
     'commonName': 'xpto',
     'calendar': [
       {
         'day': '1',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '2',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '3',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '4',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '5',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '6',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '7',
         'color': 'weekend'
       },
       {
         'day': '8',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '9',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '10',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '11',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '12',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '13',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '14',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '15',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '16',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '17',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '18',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '19',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '20',
         'color': 'weekend'
       },
       {
         'day': '21',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '22',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '23',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '24',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '25',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '26',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '27',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '28',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '29',
         'color': 'normal'
       },
       {
         'day': '30',
         'color': 'normal'
       }
     ]
   }
 ];
component.set("v.commonMemberCalendarList", tableRow);
```

},

the attribute that holds this JSON is the following:

```
<aura:attribute name="commonMemberCalendarList" type="Object[]"     />
```

I then bind the attribute to a child component in the following manner:

```
<c:RVT_CalendarEventsGanttMonthly commonMemberCalendarList="{!v.commonMemberCalendarList}"  />
```

My problem arises in the child component when I try to iterate it and get the day and color attributes from the JSON. This is how I´m doing that:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.commonMemberCalendarList}" var="member" indexVar="indexTop">
        <tr>
            <td class="member-row">
                <article class="slds-card slds-p-vertical_xxx-small">
                    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                        <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">

                            <lightning:avatar src="...................."
                                              class="slds-avatar_circle"                fallbackIconName="standard:avatar" alternativeText="Salesforce"/>
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#" title="Team Member Vacations">
                                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small">{!member.commonName}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </td>
            <td class="daysList">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.commonMemberCalendarList.calendar}" var="days" indexVar="index">
                    <th class="days-wrapper">
                        <div class="{!'slds-truncate slds-align_absolute-center days ' + days.color}" title="day"> {!days.day}</div>
                    </th>
                </aura:iteration>
            </td>
        </tr>                                               
 </aura:iteration>
```

I can only get the commonName value, when I try to get the calendar values i don´t seem to be able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `commonName` you are starting from a `member` object taken the list:

- `{!member.commonName}`

but for `calendar` you are mistakenly starting from the list itself:

- `{!v.commonMemberCalendarList.calendar}`

rather than starting from an object taken from the list e.g. your `member` variable.

Comment: thank you @Keith C, didn´t notice that. The second iteration worked with : 
  `<aura:iteration items="{!member.calendar}" var="days" indexVar="index">`